# Java Eclipse formatter plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Hello could somebody recommend to me some good Java Eclipse formatter plugin?

Because Eclipse doesn't have proper built-in code formatting (Especially for JavaDoc comments) I would like to use some external tool which is accepting Java coding standards and recommendation.

BTW: If is possible to import some configuration with defined coding standards for selected language will be great to mention it here.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in Java Code Style Formatter customization tool in Eclipse? You can customize the profile to modify how Eclipse formats your code. Goto **Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter**

Comment: Uh, Eclipse *does* have a built-in formatter... But whether it's "proper", I don't know

Comment: Can you show an example what you wanted to do and eclipse formatter was not able to do it ?